# UWP app project structure for Win8.1 backward compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, uwp

I am writing a new UWP app, which I would like to reuse as much of the business logic code (in the ViewModel layer) as I can to create a separate WPF app which will run on Windows 7/8/8.1

I am using the MVVM Light toolkit to aid with this

My current solution structure has 4 projects: one Model, one ViewModel, one UWP app and one WPF application, but I am struggling with setting up the ViewModel in such a way that it is able to target both 7/8/8.1 and 10.

Looking at [Oren Novotny's blog](https://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/) my thinking was to set-up the ViewModel to target the net45 and netcore45 frameworks (alongside the UAP framework) which would cover both Windows 8/8.1 Store Apps and .NET 4.5 Desktop apps, but I am unsure how complex this would make the code itself as this is the first time I am going through this.

1. Has anyone seen any good articles on this type of problem? All of the articles I have found talk about upgrading apps from 8.1 to 10, but not writing app to minimise coding effort when supporting both platforms
2. I guess I will need 2 different Views: one Blank Universal Windows app and one classic WPF application, but will I also need to have 2 separate ViewModel projects as well: classic desktop dll (for <= Win 8.1) and Universal Windows Class Library? Or can I build a single dll using the framework targeting that Oren Novotny's post suggests?

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Compiler directives will certainly be needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > I am writing a new UWP app, which I would like to reuse as much of the business logic code (in the ViewModel layer) as I can to create a separate WPF app which will run on Windows 7/8/8.1

In this case, you only need to create a portable class library which targets to .NET 4.6 and UWP in Visual Studio 2015.

> Looking at Oren Novotny's blog my thinking was to set-up the ViewModel to target the net45 and netcore45 frameworks (alongside the UAP framework) which would cover both Windows 8/8.1 Store Apps and .NET 4.5 Desktop apps

Currently, we cannot create a portable library which cover both UWP and Windows 8/8.1 Store App. As an alternative way, I suggest you using the Share Project which can be referenced by Windows Store App 8/8.1, WPF net45/net46 and UWP project.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, that currently looks about the closest I am going to get to code reuse. Sadly (but understandably), it doesn't allow the addition of Nuget packages, so I might have to take a different approach in using MVVM Light.

Comment: FWIW Rico, MVVM Light currently doesn't install on classic PCLs. Using PCLs last night was looking promising until I hit that issue. I am not completely tied to MVVM Light just yet, so will look at alternative ways of achieving the same result.